# Why isn't my UILabel getting set?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have been stuck on a problem for hours now, and can not seem to figure this out. I am new to Objective-C and it is really annoying me that I can not get this. I am trying to get the `NSLog` values displayed in `bmiLabel`, but my bmiLabel always shows `NULL`.

This is my code:
ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *num1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *num2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bmiLabel;
- (IBAction)bmiButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize num1, num2, resultLabel, bmiLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

- (IBAction)bmiButton:(id)sender
{
float sum = [self.num2.text floatValue] / ([self.num1.text floatValue] *
[self.num1.text floatValue]);
NSString *Output = nil;
Output = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", sum];
self.resultLabel.text = Output;

NSString *mystring;
NSString * bmi = [[NSString alloc] NSStringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];
self.bmiLabel.text = bmi;

if(sum <= 18.5)
{
    NSLog(@"You are underweight", mystring);

}
if(sum <= 18.5)
{
    NSLog(@"you are normal");
}

if (sum <= 25.0)
{
    NSLog(@"You are overweight");
}

if(sum <= 30)
{
NSLog(@"You are obese");
}

}
@end
```

Comment: Connor, jeez explain my problem would actually help huh. Sorry about that. I am trying to get the strings to print to bmiLabel but it keep stating null.

Comment: Include all error messages!!  We can't always guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, trying to be a little psychic, I note that you're not actually putting anything in the BMI case.  Try this instead:

```
- (IBAction)bmiButton:(id)sender {
    float sum = [self.num2.text floatValue] / ([self.num1.text floatValue] *
                         [self.num1.text floatValue]);

    NSString *Output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", sum];
    self.resultLabel.text = Output;

    NSString *mystring= nil;

    if (sum <= 18.5) {
        mystring = @"You are underweight";
    } else if (sum <= 25.0) {
        mystring = @"you are normal";
    } else if (sum <= 30.0){
        mystring = @"You are overweight";
    } else {
        mystring = @"You are obese:";
    }
    self.bmiLabel.text = mystring;

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I was going crazy on this. You made it beyond simple. I see the error now.

Comment: @user3399761, Please accept this kind sir's answer as demonstration of your gratitude. Plus it helps others find the correct answer. :)

Comment: Josiah, Thank you for pointing that out. I was trying to give the comment yesterday but did not see the green mark. I just did it thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're asking, but there is an error here:

```
NSString *mystring;
NSString * bmi = [[NSString alloc] NSStringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];
self.bmiLabel.text = bmi;
```

First off, your string format setters:

```
[[NSString alloc] NSStringWithFormat:@"someformat: %@", someVariable];
```

Should be:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"someformat: %@", someVariable];
```

If however, those were correct, this would still have this problem:

```
NSString * bmi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];
```

Is very strange when mystring is already a string. It's equivelant to:

```
NSString * bmi = mystring;
```

Basically, those three lines are equivelant to:

```
NSString * mystring;
self.bmiLabel.text = mystring;
```

#### Answer

The problem is, you never assigned a value to mystring

Comment: I can not believe I missed that. Now I am annoyed at myself. Thank you Logan

Answer (score 0):

I think `[[NSString alloc] NSStringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];` code has a problem. Try below code

```
 NSString *mystring;
 NSString * bmi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];
 self.bmiLabel.text = bmi;
```

Also you must initialize `mystring`. If you don't `mystring` always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not useful because you bmi is going to be an empty string. So bmiLabel will be empty.

```
NSString *mystring;
NSString * bmi = [[NSString alloc] NSStringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];
self.bmiLabel.text = bmi;
```

The rest of your code is fine. Although in my opinion you use too much objects in your code. For example, Your NSString is not necessary, you can write this

```
float sum = [self.num2.text floatValue] / ([self.num1.text floatValue] *
[self.num1.text floatValue]);
self.resultLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", sum];
```

Comment: I see what you mean, noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This:

**[[NSString alloc] NSStringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];**

StringWithFormat is a class method which would be sent to the class:

```
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some string"];
```

This tells the class to give you a string which is already allocated and initialized.

In your case you should (can) use:

```
string = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"some string"];
```

Also, about this line in your code:

```
NSString * bmi = [[NSString alloc] NSStringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring];
```

you could just do this:

```
[[self bmiLabel]setText:[[NSString alloc]initWithString:mystring]];
```

or if you prefer dot notation

```
self.bmiLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:mystring]];
```

Comment: Don't understand how you are not getting a warning about that, there is no "NSStringWithFormat" method  typo?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot and was trying everything and anything at that point. Your help was extremely useful. Thank you.